# How to integrate third party JS libraries into my React JS app

Tags: jquery, reactjs, tablesorter, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to transform my existing app developed with html JS and jQuery this app use third party libraries like (boostrap JS & tableSorter JS datepicker  ).

How to integrate them into a react app to keep animation table sort without redeveloping them with react .

```
import "./js/jquery.tablesorter";
import "./js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets";
import "./js/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/moment";
import "./js/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min";
import "./js/bootstrap-select.min";

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import History from "./History";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div id="page" className="clearfix">
      <Header />
      <History />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("login"));
```

The console how jQuery conflict and other JS error for integrated JS file

Please give me solution how integrate these libraries.

Comment: You shouldn't. Do not mix jQuery or similar libs with React. You can of course, but it's bad practice because lead to unpredictable code and difficult to mantain.

Comment: Many of JS libraries have react-adapted packages in the npm registry. So you can look up the ones that you are interested in and add them to your project as dependencies. I.e. this one for datetime-picker:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker